# Write a credit report dispute letter without including the report?

Tags: credit-report, dispute

I need to dispute several items on my credit report, but since my report is 46 pages printed (38 without the legal extras they have to include at the end), I don't necessarily want to include copies of the report with every dispute.  Right now, I see that I have two possible alternative options: 1) include copies of the first page (with my identifiable information) and the page that has the disputed item, or 2) reference the information some way in the letter, and don't include a copy of the report at all.  Are either of these two options desirable from the credit bureau's side?  Or should I just shell out the extra for mailing the full report on each dispute?  Thanks

Comment: Mention: Location, nature of dispute or items, CRAs involved and whether you have first got in touch with them.

Comment: Shell out another $1 on postage and be done with that

Answer (score 2):

Copying littleadv comment as answer.

Shell out another $1 on postage and be done with that

It doesn't make sense to get mailer back asking that info is not adequate ...

Comment: It's not just postage; photocopying costs money and so does printing (in terms of ink cartridges). 10 disputes is 460 pages, at 10 cents a page you're looking at an extra $5. Which is still not a lot, but 5 times more than your quoted cost ;)